# Pronoun modifying word after it?

Tags: grammar-identification

> wenn sie jemanden besser(en) finden koennte.

My question is regarding the bracketed "en" in the above sentence. Why is it there?

Comment: It would help, if would would identify the adjective and noun you assume to have found. Hint: *jemand* is an indefinite pronoun.

Answer (score 2):

If you find someone **"besser"** than you still find the same person, but just better in a sense that you like them more.

Another example for **"besser"** in your example is that you find a better way to find someone in a direct sense of finding a person, as in searching for them.

But if you find a **"besseren"** than you find someone else you like more e.g. and its not the same person anymore.

The brackets are probably there to indicate that there are multiple possibilities to use the word.

Answer (score 1):

The German verb "finden" has two meanings: (1), "find" something one looked for, (2), with an adjective, "think it is", (nothing to do with looking for something!), such as "das finde ich gut" = "I think that's good".
Therefore "jemanden besseren finden" is "find a better person" (by looking for them) , whereas "jemanden besser finden" would be understood as "prefer someone" (over someone else who was spoken about earlier).
In theory, "jemanden besser finden" could be "have less trouble in finding someone", but that's not what would be understood unless you put the stress, in speaking, on "finden" rather than on "besser".
Not being a native speaker of English, I am not sure whether "find" can be used in sense (2) as well, but I'm inclined to doubt it.